# D'où vient précisément le mot « parkour »?

Tags: étymologie, néologismes

Le mot *[parkour](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkour)* est bien sûr une déformation de *parcours*. Quelle est son origine précise, et comment s'est-il diffusé ? Si j'en crois [Wikipedia anglophone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkour#Terminology), le mot [date de 1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_parkour) et serait dû à David Belle et Hubert Koundé ou peut-être Sébastien Foucan. Est-ce une orthographe de potache ou du parler SMS ? Comment s'est-il répandu, au point de faire son arrivée aux États-Unis dès 2002 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je cite ce que je viens de lire sur [ce lien](http://www.power-of-parkour.blogfa.com/post/2) car l'explication me paraît logique et concorde avec l'ensemble de ce qui a été mentionné précédemment:

> Le parcours" was the original word passed down to David Belle from his
>   father Raymond Belle. This was the term Raymond used when speaking to
>   David about the training he had done. The term derives from "parcours
>   du combattant", the classic obstacle-course method of military
>   training proposed by Georges Hébert, but the term "le parcours" was
>   used by Raymond to encompass all of his training including climbing,
>   jumping, running, balancing, and the other methods he undertook in his
>   personal athletic advancement. One day when David Belle was on a film
>   set, he showed his 'Speed Air Man' video to Hubert Koundé, who
>   suggested to change the "c" of "parcours" to a "k" because it was more
>   dynamic and stronger, and to remove the silent "s" for the same
>   reason. Belle liked the idea and officially changed the name of his
>   discipline to "parkour

Answer (score 7):

J'aime cette question car je trouve la discipline fascinante. En 1999 David Belle a eu le droit a un entretien avec Claire Callogirou (ethnologue) en tant que fondateur du "parcours" et membre des yamakasi. A l'époque on disait donc "parcours", ou en tout cas l'orthographe standard ne choquait pas le fondateur de la discipline plus de ça.

L'article est ici : http://www.wmaker.net/parkour/attachment/39810/
A noter que l'orthographe standard du mot parcours était aussi utilisée par les journaux de l'époque (l'équipe par exemple).

Personnellement, je crois que la relaxation en parkour a eu pour but l'internationalisation, le mot parkour étant utilisé pour désigner la discipline dans toutes les langues. Ceci étant, je n'en ai aucune preuve...

Comment: Je note que l'article me parait mal écrit : quel est le sujet de la partie « et devient le groupe Yamakasi » ? Aussi, rien que la première phrase me fait mal au cœur…

Answer (score -1):

le Parkour existait déjà en 1973 , origine  ?
je pense Marvel Comics et Spiderman , mais je n'affirme rien.
mais déja a 14 ans on appelait cela un Parkour
Qui consisté a ne pas posé les pieds sur le sols de A au point B 
par les toits les arbres ect.. , tout pour se rompre le cou
ne le faites pas ! :p